# Como gerar um filtro para retirar outliers de uma série temporal no Matlab?

Tags: matemática, matlab, filtro

gostaria de criar um filtro passa-baixa para remover outliers de uma série temporal.

São dados de temperatura superficial do mar (tsm), nesta série existem alguns dados que são outliers e não sei muito bem como criar um filtro passa-baixa, alguém poderia me ajudar?

OBS: Os dados de tsm estão em forma de vetor. A frequência de amostragem eu acho que é de 5 minutos.

Tô começando a mexer no Matlab agora e não sei bem como fazer isso.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Existem técnicas diferentes para propósitos diferentes, mas de uma forma geral a remoção de Outliers são identificados e removidos de um vetor na seguinte forma:

```
X = 1:100;
X = X';
noise = randn(100,1);
noise2 = 10*randn(100,1);
noise(11:20:91) = noise2(11:20:91);
Y = 3*X + 2 + noise;
stats = regstats(Y,X,'linear');
potential_outlier = stats.cookd > 4/length(X);
X(potential_outlier)
scatter(X,Y, 'b.')
hold on
scatter(X(potential_outlier),Y(potential_outlier), 'r.')
```

Podes conferir melhor esse código [aqui](http://%25%20Create%20a%20vector%20of%20X%20values%20X%20=%201:100;%20X%20=%20X';%20%25%20Create%20a%20noise%20vector%20noise%20=%20randn(100,1);%20%25%20Create%20a%20second%20noise%20value%20where%20sigma%20is%20much%20larger%20noise2%20=%2010*randn(100,1);%20%25%20Substitute%20noise2%20for%20noise1%20at%20obs#%20(11,%2031,%2051,%2071,%2091)%20%25%20Many%20of%20these%20points%20will%20have%20an%20undue%20influence%20on%20the%20model%20%20noise(11:20:91)%20=%20noise2(11:20:91);%20%25%20Specify%20Y%20=%20F(X)%20Y%20=%203*X%20+%202%20+%20noise;%20%25%20Cook's%20Distance%20for%20a%20given%20data%20point%20measures%20the%20extent%20to%20%20%25%20which%20a%20regression%20model%20would%20change%20if%20this%20data%20point%20%20%25%20were%20excluded%20from%20the%20regression.%20Cook's%20Distance%20is%20%20%25%20sometimes%20used%20to%20suggest%20whether%20a%20given%20data%20point%20might%20be%20an%20outlier.%20%25%20Use%20regstats%20to%20calculate%20Cook's%20Distance%20stats%20=%20regstats(Y,X,'linear');%20%25%20if%20Cook's%20Distance%20%3E%20n/4%20is%20a%20typical%20treshold%20that%20is%20used%20to%20suggest%20%25%20the%20presence%20of%20an%20outlier%20potential_outlier%20=%20stats.cookd%20%3E%204/length(X);%20%25%20Display%20the%20index%20of%20potential%20outliers%20and%20graph%20the%20results%20X(potential_outlier)%20scatter(X,Y,%20'b.')%20hold%20on%20scatter(X(potential_outlier),Y(potential_outlier),%20'r.')) com explicações